# Consumir un webservice desde un weblogic

Tags: java, http, soap, weblogic

tengo una aplicación Java que opera en WebLogic Server. Esta aplicación consume un servicio web de otro servidor completamente diferente. Mientras la aplicación funciona adecuadamente en mi entorno local, en producción, me encuentro con un error ya que la llamada al servicio web está devolviendo valores nulos. Es importante destacar que todo funciona correctamente en localhost, lo que sugiere que el servicio web que estoy consumiendo y la implementación del código son correctos. Tengo la sospecha de que podría deberse a alguna configuración faltante en el entorno de producción de WebLogic.

Según recuerdo, alguna vez configuré algo en mi weblogic (localhost) para permitir la conexión con otros webservice, no estoy seguro, pero bueno, ¿Alguien sabe si me falta activar algún permiso en el weblogic (de producción) para lograr la conexión con otros webservice?.

me gustaría incluir el error que devuelve el log, pero solo encontré el error en 'Diagnosticos', 'Archivos log' , 'domain log', pero el error no es muy especifico, ¿Alguien sabe como puedo encontrar un archivo log más completo o cual es el que debería revisar?